# how can i send an array as props using this.props.navigation.navigate?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My array is

```
     this.state={
          locations:[
              {name: 'kerala'},
              {name: 'maharashtra'},
              {name: 'tamilnadu'},
           ]}
```

and my component is

```
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={(e)=>this.props.navigation.navigate('MultiSelector',{
        locations:this.state.locations})}>
       <View><Text>select</Text></View>   
     </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

i send the props as above .

and Multiselector component is like

```
     render(){
        const { params} = this.props.navigation.state;
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        const locations = navigation.getParam('locations','kerala')
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
          {
            locations.map((item,index)=>{
              return(
             <View key={index}><Text>{item.name}</Text>
             </View>)
            })
           }
          </View>
        )
```

I didn't get the locations array as props in multiselector it takes the default value only(when i tested). and it makes an error locations.map is not a function .can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access this using:

```
const locations = this.props.navigation.state.params.locations;
```

Or

Use library `StackNavigatorHelper` :

```
StackNavigator({
     Home: { screen: StackNavigatorHelper.paramsToProps(Home) },
     MultiSelector: { screen: StackNavigatorHelper.paramsToProps(MultiSelector) }
});
```

Library link: https://github.com/dayitv89/react-navigation-helper

Comment: This isn't really a solution. The react navigation plugin is now in version 2.+ and he is using it correctly according to the docs. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

Answer (score 1):

you can doing something like this:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={(e)=>this.props.navigation.navigate('MultiSelector',{...this.state.locations})}> //change your code to use ...
   <View><Text>select</Text></View>   
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

and the rest is up to you